# How to shutdown the Quarz scheduler when the application in Application Server is ShutDown

Tags: java, spring, websphere, quartz-scheduler

I had a situation. I configured the Spring Batch to my Enterprise application. I deployed it in Websphere application server. As long as the server starts, the load on init servlet calls the Quarzlauncher.java(my local class which internally configured using quartz-job-launcher-context.xml). And schedules each 30 mins. When I stop the application in the app server, the quartz job still running. i.e its triggering the job still at each 30 mins.
 How to shut down the quartz when I stop the application?

If anyone knows how to stop the scheduler in this case . Please give the solution .